# Give proofs by induction for the following relation properties.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, relations

1. Let $R$ and $S$ be relations such that $R\subseteq S$. Prove that $R^n$ is a subset of $S^n$ for all positive integers $n$.
2. Let $R$ be a symmetric relation. Prove that $R^n$ is symmetric for all positive integers $n$.

This is what I have done up to now. I am not used to proving relation properties.

1. The result is true for $n=1$, suppose $R^{n-1}$ is a subset of $S^{n-1}$.

   Note that if $A$ is a subset of $C$ and $B$ is a subset of $D$ then $A\times B$ is a subset of $C\times D$, thus :

   $R^n = R^{n-1} \times R$ is a subset of $S^{n-1} \times S = S^n$.

   Hence proved.
2. The result is true for $n=1$, suppose $R^{n-1}$ is symmetric.

   Let $(x_0,y_0,x_1,y_1,\dots,x_n,y_n)\in R^n=R \times R^{n-1}$

   Since $R$ is symmetric then $(y_0,x_0)\in R$.

   Since $R^{n-1}$ is symmetric then $(y_1,x_1,y_2,x_2,\dots,y_{n-1},x_{n-1})\in R^{n-1}$

   Hence $(y_0,x_0,y_1,x_1,\dots,y_n,x_n)\in R \times R^{n-1} = R^n$

   So $R^n$ is symmetric.

Comment: I am a bit confused in that you have a corresponding $y$ everywhere except in the first tuple in (b)

Comment: I am not sure if i went the right way here. Can someone help me please.

Comment: Can someone guide me on how to answer this question.

Comment: I believe you almost have it. #1 is good afaict. In #2, I noticed you are using this definition $R^n=R\times R^{n-1}$ when you should be using $R^n=R^{n-1}\times R$. From there, you should separate the pair $(x_n,y_n)$ instead but the logic is the same.

Comment: OK, thank you, so when I correct #2 I should be ok.

Comment: I believe so. You should add the correct solution and mark it as answer. I didn't want to take the credit since you were almost there.

Comment: I edited some things you missed in your answer. Once you are satisfied with an answer don't forget to mark it as an accepted answer so that others with similar questions are aware that you found a suitable answer.

Comment: Well thank you very much again. I tried to accept the answer but it is telling me that I can not.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer would be:

1. Let $R$ and $S$ be relations such that $R\subseteq S$. Prove that $R^n$ is a subset of $S^n$ for all positive integers $n$.
2. Let $R$ be a symmetric relation. Prove that $R^n$ is symmetric for all positive integers $n$.

This is what I have done up to now. I am not used to proving relation properties.

1. The result is true for $n=1$, suppose $R^{n-1}$ is a subset of $S^{n-1}$.

   Note that if $A$ is a subset of $C$ and $B$ is a subset of $D$ then $A\times B$ is a subset of $C\times D$, thus :

   $R^n = R^{n-1} \times R$ is a subset of $S^{n-1} \times S = S^n$.

   Hence proved.
2. The result is true for $n=1$, suppose $R^{n-1}$ is symmetric.

   Let $(x_0,y_0,x_1,y_1,\dots,x_n,y_n)\in R^n=R^{n-1} \times R$

   Since $R$ is symmetric then $(y_n,x_n)\in R$.

   Since $R^{n-1}$ is symmetric then $(y_0,x_0,y_1,x_1,\dots,y_{n-1},x_{n-1})\in R^{n-1}$

   Hence $(y_0,x_0,y_1,x_1,\dots,y_n,x_n)\in R^{n-1} \times R = R^n$

   So $R^n$ is symmetric.